# MVC handling Collection Item Index in Partial view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections, indexing, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I Have a ViewModel with a collection inside such as:

```
public class CreateCampaignViewModel : ControlPanelViewModel
{
    [RequiredField]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<AdvertisementViewModel> Advertisements { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

in the View, if i use it like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Advertisements.Count; i++)
{
  <fieldset style="z-index: 0;">
  <legend>מודעה</legend>
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Advertisements[i].Title)">כותרת הפרסומת</label></td>
      <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Advertisements[i].Title)</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </fieldset>
}
```

everything is good, and i can see the list when i post the form...

but i want to nest the AdvertisementEditor in a Partial View hence my view becomes:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Advertisements.Count; i++)
{
   Html.RenderPartial("AdvertisementEditor", Model.Advertisements[i]);
}
```

and my Partial:

```
@model Pushed.Models.AdvertisementViewModel

<fieldset style="z-index: 0;">
    <legend>מודעה</legend>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Title)">כותרת הפרסומת</label></td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

My problem is that Now, when i post the form, i dont get the values in the TextBox for each Advertisement.

This is logical, cause now my `<input>` tags dont have the 'advertisement[1].Title' name, but only 'Title' which does not exist in my containing model.

**how can i create a partial that is reflecting a single collection item with it's indecies so it will repost correctly with the form?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

found a solution, Can't believe i didn't find this before!

there are two ways to tell MVC.NET to prefix input fields:

1. create EditorTemplate instead of PartialView... and it will work just great.
2. define `TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`

calling the Partial View as illustrated:

```
@{ 
  Html.RenderPartial("TargetAudienceParameters", Model.TargetAudienceParameter, 
      new ViewDataDictionary {
           TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo {
               HtmlFieldPrefix = "Advertisements[4]" // 4 being an example
           } 
      }); 
 }
```

Comment: Actually the "official" approach to this is to use EditorTemplate instead : See Patrick's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33397505/71906

Answer (score 1):

In my project when I trigger with this problem I'm starting to use ajax query, which hit after user away from textbox. It's not clearest solution but works for me. Also you need to generate special Id in partial view for each group element. Smth about:

```
function eduFacilityTableSave() {
    $('#eduFacilityTable tr input[type="text"],#eduFacilityTable tr select').change(function () {
        var parId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        var parentName = parId.replace(/\d+/g, '');
        var parentId = parId.replace(/\D+/g, '');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var text = $(this).val();
        //alert(text);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Form/SaveFromForm/",
            data: { id: id, parentId: parentId, parentName: parentName, text: text },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //
            }
        });
    });
}

public JsonResult SaveFromForm(string id, string parentId, string parentName, string text) {
            if (parentName == "eduFacility") {
                var edufacility = _repository.GetEduFacilityById(Convert.ToInt32(parentId));
                if (id == "EntryYearId") {
                    edufacility.EntryYearId = Convert.ToInt32(text);
                }
                if (id == "FinishYearId") {
                    edufacility.FinishYearId = Convert.ToInt32(text);
                }
                if (id == "FullName") {
                    edufacility.FullName = text;
                }
                if (id == "Speciality") {
                    edufacility.Speciality = text;
                }
                if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                    _repository.UpdateEduFacility(edufacility);
                    _repository.Save();
                }
            }
            return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```