# MVC5 Form with repeating partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC form where I have to loop through a database recordset and continue to display partial views that contain the data.

This is an input form.  Meaning if the database contains 50 records, each with "FirstName", how do I handle this?  There are going to be 50 "FirstName" input fields.

I am using the Entity Framework.  I have not had to use this pattern in the past and am not sure how this is properly handled under MVC5.

The parent class takes in a List<> of these things then loops and displays the partial views that contain the form.  The BeginForm() is in the parent view.  The partials take in the singular objects from the List<> to use as the form fields.

My question relates to handle to handle this on the *server*, meaning in the HttpPost method.  Do I have that handle the original List<> object that was passed to the parent view?  Will that contain all of the updates automatically to each child object contained within?

Comment: Not enough information to answer this question.  Are you saving per item, or the whole group?

Comment: I am going to need to save the whole group.  I edited to explain how the parent/partial relationship is setup.

Comment: You need to use an `EditorTemplate` so that the form controls are correctly named with indexers and will bind to your collection when you post.

Comment: Blah.  I was hoping to avoid that route.  I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: @Patrick, Why were you _hoping to avoid that route_? It just means putting you partial in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder and renaming it match the name of your class. Then in the main view its just `@EditorFor(m => m)` - its less code than you currently have

Comment: @Stephen Murke - Just wanted to say that indeed, EditorFor was quick and painless and properly generates the unique IDs and names in the HTML for every object in the List<>.  If you want to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as recommended by Stephen Murke, is just to use an EditorTemplate for the custom object.

So now the parent view has simply:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.HistoryDetail)
```

Where m.HistoryDetail is a List<>.  I simply moved the partial in an EditorTemplates sub-folder and renamed it to match the object name.

The MVC framework takes care of the rest and I get resulting HTML that has unique IDs and names for each item in the List<>:

```
<textarea class="form-control" cols="25" id="HistoryDetail_2__ReferralComments" name="HistoryDetail[2].ReferralComments" rows="5" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100 %;">
    Comments for the Approval Level
</textarea>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="HistoryDetail[2].ReferralComments" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a partial view, which contains the following:

```
@model string
<label for="name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="name" value="@Model" />
```

This partial view it should be contained in a view, in this view you will pass a model, whose on of its properties would be a list of first names. Then you just have to write a foreach:

```
@foreach(var firstName in Model.FirstNames)
{
    @Html.PartialView("_NameOfYourPartialView", firstName)
}
```

Comment: That's how I have it, it all works perfectly in terms of how it's displayed on the client.  My question is how do I handle this on the server in the HttpPost method, since there are repeating partials.  Do I just pass back the original List<> that the parent view takes in?

Comment: @Patrick No, you just pass only the values that are in you form, the values that are in your partial view and not the values in all the partials.

Comment: With an @Html.BeginForm() in the parent, what am I expecting as the parameter to the HttpPost?  It would have to be a List<> or I won't get all 50 records I need to get into the database that are coming from all the partials.